# How to uncommit a commit after many commits have been added?

Tags: git

I know that if I commit something, I can uncommit it like so:

```
get reset HEAD~1
```

That will effectively "go back" one commit. My problem is that I did a commit, and then a pull. In fact, i did a bunch of pulls, adding more and more code. So I ended up with:

```
--> Other User Commit A  <<-- WAS PUSHED
--> Other User Commit B  <<-- WAS PUSHED
--> MY COMMIT <<---- This is what must be UNDONE, that was never pushed
--> Other User Commit E  <<-- WAS PUSHED
--> Other User Commit F  <<-- WAS PUSHED
```

So reset HEAD~1 will simply get rid of "Other User Commit A". But I only need "MY COMMIT" removed, which was never pushed.

Any ideas as to how to get rid of this commit of mine?

(FYI, what happened was I commited a 1.6 Gb file by accident, and couldn't figure out why push didn't work, but kept working and pulling new code as it came in... but never pushed this until I just realised now that this big file musn't be in the commit...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

**UPDATE**

The best solution would be one that would allow me to "un-add" the file I added.

Comment: Are there others using your branch?  Would it be fine for you to rebase it/rewrite history?

Comment: I cant rewrite the history... i must only be able to remove that one

Comment: Considering that it's a 1.6GB file in your code repository, I think you *have* to rewrite the history to be able to get it out of the repo, lest everyone that pulls your code in be forced to pull that down when they fetch your branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you never pushed this branch, you should be fine rewriting the history and removing the bad commit.  To do this, you can do an interactive rebase on your branch:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

This will bring up a screen showing you the last 5 commits in the history of your branch.  It should look something like this:

```
pick dl3n2l2 Other User Commit A
pick be7mme2 Other User Commit B
pick loc83ns MY COMMIT
pick af8uo31 Other User Commit E
pick dl983md Other User Commit F
```

Now *delete* the line containing your commit labelled `MY COMMIT`.  Just remove that line from the file, save and close.  This should effectively remove the bad commit from your branch, and you should now be able to push to the remote.

Comment: The answer given by @Juan would also work, but it completely abandons the branch.

Comment: After doing this, I get: error: Untracked working tree file 'public_html/sites/default/files/advagg_js/js__OFsU.js' would be overwritten by merge.

Comment: What can you tell me about this file?  Was it part of the bad commit?

Comment: Wouldn't you have a different history with this solution? I mean, afterwards you wouldn't be able to pull or push unless you force it, right?

Comment: @Juan He wasn't able to push at all because of the large file.  So I imagine he would be able to fast-forward the remote branch after removing the bad commit.

Comment: That file should not have been part of this bad commit, but it may have been. It almost looks like all of the caches JS files were added to the commit too.

Comment: After I do the rebase, I get the error that that file would be overriden. If I then push, its as if though the rebase never happened and it tries to do the whole commit again. So I need to resolve this file that is going to be overridden somehow.

Comment: But if you rebase you ll change the history of the newer commits, even if you skip the conflicting one

Comment: @Juan If he pulled on top of the bad commit then the commits on top already are likely different.  They are probably merge commits, so I don't see a penalty in rewriting the history.

Comment: Looks like some progress on my side after I did: "git reset --hard" ... not yet sure if that was wise...

Comment: @coderama Try going ahead and overwriting the untracked file, unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen .. I did try to delete the file it mentions, but then it throws the error with another file. So it happens over and over... after I did "git reset --hard", it is now rebasing. I can see: "Rebasing (14/35)" --> again, not sure if this is good or bad yet.... it is taking very long so will report back in a bit. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: It worked! I think. The git history looks the way I expect it to, but now when I push I get "remote: unpack error Out of memory loading unknown object
error: unpack failed: error Out of memory loading unknown object" ... I think I can resolve that, so will mark this answer as yes the moment I am able to push!

Answer (score 2):

As you never pushed your commit, if you don't want to change the history the best option is probably to pull a brand new branch. Let's assume that the branch you re working on is called feature, you could just do:

```
git checkout "Other User Commit E' code"
git branch -f feature
git pull origin feature
```

This will just get you a fresh copy of the latest code of feature branch, which should be good enough if you never pushed your commit.
`git branch -f` will bring the desired branch to whichever commit you are currently in.

Comment: @coderama, this way you would "un-add" the file, as you are just reverting to the current remote branch state, forgetting about your local changes

Comment: In retrospect, this would probably have been easier :/

Answer (score 1):

You can revert a commit without touching the other changes that were pushed on top via:

```
git revert <commit>
```

That will reverse just the changes in that one commit. Once pushed, it will be like that commit never happened (though the git history will still be there.)

Another option is to just delete the file, and commit the deletion.

Comment: I don't think this is the best option, because the bad commit, containing the massive binary file, might still get pushed to the remote.

Comment: Thats what I want to avoid... i.e. committing the huge binary file